# Attach a .Change event to a Radiobutton list. (Values bound at run time)

Tags: jquery

How can i attach a .change event to a radiobuttonlist which has its values bound at runtime

```
rbSecurity.dataSource = Data();
rbSecurity.dataBind();
```

I want to hide a dropdownlist (ddlContact) based on certain selection in the rbSecurity

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$("#<%=rbSecurity.ClientID%> input[name*='Security']").change(function () {
            if ($("input[@name=GroupName]:checked").val() != 'Value1') {
                $('#<%=ddlApprovers.ClientID %>').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#<%=ddlApprovers.ClientID %>').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a change handler to every radio button in your `RadioButtonList` that takes action only when the radio button is checked. For instance:

**Control declaration:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbSecurity" runat="server" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#<%=rbSecurity.ClientID%> input:radio").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        if (this.value == "Value1") {
            $("#<%=ddlContact.ClientID %>").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=ddlContact.ClientID %>").hide();
        }
    }
}).filter(":checked").change();
```

Notice in the jQuery snippet I also suggest you fire an initial change event for the radio button that is checked on page load.

In the code's if block, you could test `this.value` to see if it is part of a valid set of values and call `.show()` for a particular selector, and if it is not, `.hide()` that selector instead.

Comment: my radio button list is contained in a table td element, and also I have attached a css class to the radio button (many to many) element after the binding.

Comment: I've edited the code to be less general-case so that you can see how it would look with your specific implementation.

Comment: I modified your code to this$("#<%=rbSecurity.ClientID%> input:radio").change(function () {
        alert("changed");
        
    }).filter(":checked").change();
I dont see an alert when the selection changes

Comment: Then you'll want to debug your JavaScript to see if anything above that code is failing and causing the execution of the function to cease. You can see how many elements are targeted by the selector by alerting or calling console.log() on `$("#<%=rbSecurity.ClientID%> input:radio").length`.